# Mean of conditional mean in discrete case

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to prove, that: $$ E[ E[X |Y]]= E[X] $$ for X,Y discrete random variables.

Proof:
$$ E[ E[X |Y]] = \sum_y E[X|Y=y] \cdot P(Y=y) = \sum_y \sum_x \frac{P(X=x, Y=y)}{P(Y=y)}\cdot P(Y=y)$$

$$ \underbrace{=}_{Fubini}  \sum_x x \sum_y P(X=x, Y=y)=? $$

Why should be  $\sum_y P(X=x, Y=y) = P(X=x)$ ?

Comment: It follows directly from definition, unless perhaps you work only on discrete random variables, and you defined the concept for them?

Comment: Which defintion do you mean?

Comment: $E[X|Y]$ is an $Y$ measurable random variable such that for every $Y$-measurable set $A$ we have $E[1_AE[X|Y]] = E[1_AX]$. This is the definition. In particular we can take $A = \Omega$.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know this definition. Is there any argument for  $\sum_y P(X=x, Y=y) = P(X=x)$

Comment: Yes, this is just countable additivity of measure $P$. $\bigcup_y\{X = x, Y = y\} = \{X = x\}$

Comment: @Jakobian: Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(X = x) = P(\cup_{y \in \Omega_y} \{X = x\}\cap \{Y=y\}) = \sum_{y \in \Omega_y}P(\{X =x\} \cap\{Y=y\}),$$ since $y$ can take only one value at a time and $\Omega_y$ is countable. I.e. $$(\{X =x\} \cap\{Y=k\}) \cap(\{X =x\} \cap\{Y=l\}) = \emptyset$$ if $k \neq l$.

Comment: You can use \{ and \} for brackets to show up.

Comment: Thank you,I've wanted to find that out for a while.

Comment: @GradaGukovic: Thank you very much:)